# Как заменить абсолютный адрес на относительный регулярным выражением?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, url

Написал вот такой тест

```
// the domain is 'test.dev'
function test (str) {
    rep = str.replace(/^(?:https?:)?\/\/test\.dev(?:$|\/)/, "/");
    console.log('Was: ' + str + '\nNow: ' + rep);
}
test("http://test.dev/path?query=string");
test("https://test.dev/");
test("//test.dev");
test("//test.dev/?query=string");
```

, который работает и выдает

```
Was: http://test.dev/path?query=string
Now: /path?query=string

Was: https://test.dev/
Now: /

Was: //test.dev
Now: /

Was: //test.dev/?query=string
Now: /?query=string
```

Но ссылка может быть еще и такого вида (без слэша перед началом query string): `//test.dev?query=string`, и тогда регулярка выше не срабатывает. Как бы в нее попроще этот вопросительный знак воткнуть?

Из `//test.dev?query=string` должно получиться `/?query=string`.

Придется дополнить вопрос. Исходные ссылки могут быть не только на `test.dev`, но и на другие сайты (например, `test.devil`). Такие ссылки нельзя превратить в относительные, точнее можно, но это не будет иметь смысла по отношению к сайту `test.dev`, поэтому они должны оставаться как есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю заменить `rep = str.replace(/^(?:https?:)?\/\/test\.dev(?:$|\/)/, "/");` на

```
rep = str.replace(/^(?:https?:)?\/\/test\.dev(?:$|\/|(\?))/, "/$1");
                                                     ^^^^
```

Добавив захватывающую подмаску `(\?)` в качестве ещё одной альтернативы в незахватывающую группу, можно отловить знак вопроса, а потом с помощью обратной ссылки `$1` в шаблоне замены восстановить его в получаемой строке.

```js
function test (str) {
    rep = str.replace(/^(?:https?:)?\/\/test\.dev(?:$|\/|(\?))/, "/$1");
    console.log('Was: ' + str + '\nNow: ' + rep);
}
test("http://test.dev/path?query=string");
test("https://test.dev/");
test("//test.dev");
test("//test.dev/?query=string");
test("//test.dev?query=string"); // /?query=string
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто добавить * после второй группы. Это будет означать, что после .dev должно быть ноль или больше слэшей, если образно. В итоге получается так:

```
rep = str.replace(/^(?:https?:)?\/\/test\.dev(?:$|\/*)/, "/")
```

P.S. ели еще не пользуетесь подобными вещами, советую посмотреть сервис [regex101](https://regex101.com/) - удобно и с наглядными пояснениями элементов

Comment: Мне нравится, что здесь автоматом удаляется куча слэшей и нет запоминаний и подстановок в регулярке, но `http://test.devil/?query=string` => `/il/?query=string`

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, а где в вопросе упоминание ссылок не того домена? Upd: увидел дополнение..

Comment: @vp_arth, к сожалению, сразу не указал это.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто разделить строку по домену и взять правую часть.

```js
var domain = 'example.org';

[
  'http://example.org/some/path?key=value',
  'https://example.org/some/path?key=value',
  'http://example.org/?key=value',
  'http://example.org?вполне_корректная_относительная_ссылка',
  'http://example.org/',
  '//example.org/without/proto'
].forEach(function(url) {
  console.log(url.split(domain)[1]);
});

// Так же можно проверить наличие корректного домена
let list = [
  'http://example.organ/?key=value',
  'http://example.com/',
  'http://example.org/'
].map(url => {
  if (url.split('/')[2] !== domain) return url;
  return url.split(domain)[1]
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: некорректными данными может быть уже относительная ссылка вида `/url/example.org/path`